# LINQ avoid specific grouping

Tags: c#, linq

in my polynomial class all the terms consist of a List of tuples (double, uint), representing the coefficient and the exponent; a real and a natural number. The +operator implementation works great, but I was wondering if I could avoid to write two times `grouping.Sum(s => s.Item1)` It somehow feels not good, but I can't seem find a way to circumvent it.

Here is the code:

```
public static tuplePolynomial operator +(tuplePolynomial tp1, tuplePolynomial tp2)
{
    tuplePolynomial Result = new tuplePolynomial();           
    Result.Terms =
    (
        from t in tp1.Terms.Concat(tp2.Terms)
        group t by t.Item2 into grouping
        where grouping.Sum(s => s.Item1) != 0.0
        select new Tuple<double, uint>(grouping.Sum(s => s.Item1), grouping.Key)
    ).ToList();           
    return Result;
}
```

I actually merge the two polymonial's terms and group the terms with the same exponents to sum them. I filter out the terms with zero exponents. `Terms` is of type `List<Tuple<double,uint>>`.

Comment: Add a `let` clause into your query to hold the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy with the `let` clause:

```
from t in tp1.Terms.Concat(tp2.Terms)
group t by t.Item2 into grouping
let sum = grouping.Sum(s => s.Item1)
where sum != 0.0
select new Tuple<double, uint>(sum, grouping.Key)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just move your `where` condition outside and apply it after projecting the new tuples.

Then you only apply the `Sum` operator on each group once and filter the resulting zero sums out before you call `ToList`.

The code would look something like:

`Result.Terms = ( ... ).Where(t => t.Item1 != 0).ToList();`